# How to connect to remote Hive server without hive downloaded?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to access a Hive cluster without Hive downloaded on my machine. I read on here that I just need a jdbc client to do so. I have a url, username and password for the hive cluster. I have tried making a hive-site.xml with these, as well as doing it programmatically, although this method does not seem to have a place to input username and password. No matter what I do, it seems that the following error is keeping me from accessing hive: 
    Unable to instantiate 
    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

I feel like this is because I do not have Hive downloaded on my computer from the answers to this error online. What exactly do I need to do here to access it without hive downloaded, or do I actually have to download it? Here is my code for reference:

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("interfacing spark sql to hive metastore without 
configuration file") \
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "https://prod-fmhdinsight- 
eu.azurehdinsight.net") \
.enableHiveSupport() \
.getOrCreate()

data = [('First', 1), ('Second', 2), ('Third', 3), ('Fourth', 4), 
('Fifth', 5)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
# see the frame created
df.show()
# write the frame
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("t4")
```

and the hive-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

<property> 
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name> 

    <value>https://prod-fmhdinsight-eu.azurehdinsight.net</value>
</property>
<!--
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<-->
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>https://prod-fmhdinsight-eu.azurehdinsight.net</value>
    <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>username</value>
    <description>user name for connecting to mysql server 
</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>password</value>
    <description>password for connecting to mysql server 
</description>
</property>
```

Comment: `hive.metastore.uris` shouldn't be using an HTTPs address.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have also tried things like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive`  and 
`thrift://localost:9083`   . How do I know what this is supposed to be?

Comment: do you have ambari client? if so long into it select hive and hive server2. it should give you the hive server address there

Comment: port `:9083` is the default... `thrift://` is the correct protocol... I would assume that HDInsights or Ambari would show you the correct address for accessing the metastore, but if that is an internal address, then you would have to configure that to be an external address to allow access outside the Hadoop network

Comment: You seem to be utterly confused. JDBC is JDBC is JDBC; a JDBC driver does not give a shot about `hive-site.xml` or the Metastore URIs which are used by **fat** clients (like the legacy `hive` CLI or Spark).

Comment: So take a deep breath, download a basic database UI tool like DBeaver or DBVisualizer (if you are expecting to connect from your PC), get your hands on the **_standalone_** Apache JDBC driver -- or better, the Cloudera JDBC driver, and google for setup instructions. Hopefully you don't have Kerberos auth, because that's tricky (even _very very_ tricky on Windows).

Comment: For what @Samson says - this should help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-connect-hive-jdbc-driver

Comment: A word of caution: the Apache driver and the Cloudera driver have completely different syntax for URL options.Make sure you use the correct one. Also, with the Apache driver, make sure your driver version is aligned with the server version -- don't expect any kind of forward/backward compatibility (unless by accident).

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Use `spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars` configuration property with `maven` to let Spark SQL download the required jars.

The other options are `builtin` (that simply assumes Hive 1.2.1) and a classpath of the Hive JARs (e.g. `spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars="/Users/jacek/dev/apps/hive/lib/*"`).

If your Hive metastore is available remotely via thrift protocol you may want to create `$SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

A nice feature of Hive is to define configuration properties as System properties so the above would look as follows:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell \
  --driver-java-options="-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:9083"
```

---

You may want to add the following to `conf/log4j.properties` for a more low-level logging:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$=ALL
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState=ALL
```